# selecting multiple items in an AS3 list component based on values

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've created a flash AS3 user form for sales people. When I create a user, I select multiple cities from a list component and drop them into an array. When added to the mySQL DB these entries are kept in a separte table which I can then call upon at any time using XML to bring them back into AS3. Now I'm using the same form as a user updaete form and populating it with data from previous MySQL insert.

My question is - How could I have these cities show as 'selected' on the list Component when the update form is loaded? Thus allowing the someone to add to or substract from that selection set. I'm trying to set selectedItems to match the ID's in the XML but failing miserably.
as a test I tried

```
addUser.citiesList.selectedItems = [3,4];

addUser.citiesList.selectedIndices = [3,4];
```

The selectedItems yield nothing but the selectedIndices works but I don't want to start matching indexes with Item ID's

looked all over but can't seem to find an answer. Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally got it working.
Having got the data out of the MySQL db, through PHP and into Flash as XML, I then pushed the user city values into a userCity array.
I got the AS3 list component in the form populated in the same way with all the cities.
I then used the userCity array in a nested for loop to inerate through all the cities in the list component, picking out the ones that had been previously selected and grabbing the index of each to pop into a new array which was the array used for the 'selectedindicies' and hey presto. I now have a cities list (about 36 cities) with the previously selected cities (about 5 cities) already selected and highlighted so that the user knows which cities the sales peson already manages. Now they can add or subtract from that and it will be picked up by my on change event as normal.
The Adobe resources on selectedIndices and selectedItems, for someone like me, who's learning is to say the least - pittyful...

I hope this helps someone else out...